# finding vegetarian users in Yelp data

Tags: classification, data-mining

I came across this data science question and want to know others opinions. Imagine you have the Yelp users data set which includes their browsing history, their keywords, etc. There is also a binary rule-based classifier that labels user as vegetarian or not. However, there is no label for each user to determine whether they are vegetarian or not. So the question is, how do we evaluate the rule based classifier? My first thought was to use a clustering approach (such as K-mean) over the data set to get an idea of the data and their clusters. Then we apply techniques such as association rule mining on clusters to see how different clusters are in terms of vegetarian characteristics. Does it make sense? Please let me know your thoughts on that.

Comment: Clusters will likely not get you anywhere here. They can be anything, and will likely not be related to being vegetarian at all.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Do you have any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: Get labeled data if you want to classify people as vegetarian. If necessary, spend time to label yourself...